# In XSL check if filename is not existing in another file is not working?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have written code to check if Document_Name__c from merge1.xml is not existing in Document_Name__c from merge2.xml then i need all the data in that case only from merge1 as per expected output.
XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="XMLMerge2" select="document('merge2.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="objects">
    <objects>
        <xsl:for-each select="Alert__c">
            <xsl:variable name="Email_from_merge1" select="Document_Name__c"/>
            <xsl:if
                test="
                    exists($XMLMerge2/objects/Data__c[Document_Name__c
                    != $Email_from_merge1])">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </objects>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Input: Merge1.xml--- in XSL, I am using  from here.

```
<objects>
    <Alert__c>
        <Document_Name__c>aaa.pdf</Document_Name__c>
        <CreatedDate>2017-06-19T10:55:56.000Z</CreatedDate>
    </Alert__c>
    <Alert__c>
        <Document_Name__c>file 1.pdf</Document_Name__c>
        <CreatedDate>2017-06-15T10:55:56.000Z</CreatedDate>
    </Alert__c>
    <Alert__c>
        <Document_Name__c>VICS_810_004010_US.pdf</Document_Name__c>
        <CreatedDate>2017-06-09T06:24:56.000Z</CreatedDate>
    </Alert__c>    
    <Alert__c>
        <Document_Name__c>aa.csv</Document_Name__c>
        <CreatedDate>2017-06-14T14:26:49.000Z</CreatedDate>
    </Alert__c>   
</objects>
```

Merge2.xml--- in XSL, I am using  from here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
<Data__c>
<Id>a0J3900000KNEqTEAX</Id>
<Document_Name__c>VICS_810_004010_US.pdf</Document_Name__c>
</Data__c>

<Data__c>
<Id>a0J3900000KNEqVEAX</Id>
<Document_Name__c>file 1.pdf</Document_Name__c>
</Data__c>
</objects>
```

Expected output:

```
<objects>
    <Alert__c>
        <Document_Name__c>aaa.pdf</Document_Name__c>
        <CreatedDate>2017-06-19T10:55:56.000Z</CreatedDate>
    </Alert__c>
    <Alert__c>
        <Document_Name__c>aa.csv</Document_Name__c>
        <CreatedDate>2017-06-14T14:26:49.000Z</CreatedDate>
    </Alert__c>
</objects>
```

Comment: Don't tell us it doesn't work, tell us how it fails. What output are you getting?

Comment: I fixed the formatting of merge1.xml and the expected output, but trying to do the same on merge2.xml reveals that the file isn't well-formed XML. It's therefore impossible to help you since the data you have supplied is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Now data is well form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a basic flaw in your logic. You want to test if D2 does not contain an element equal to X, but you are actually testing whether D2 contains an element that is not equal to X. These are different conditions. You want

```
test="!exists(X=Y)"
```

not

```
test="exists(X!=Y)"
```

Comment: i tried both but didnt worked. Can you please provide xsl code if possible

Comment: No, I'm happy to help you find the errors in your code but I don't provide a free coding service.